# Javascript get first, in between and last object based on dynamic length in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got a Javascript Array that initially starts of an empty, and gradually increases to a maximum, unknown length that varies each time, it could be 2 objects in the array, it could be 5 objects in the array.

My function loops over the final output of the array with it's final length and aims to get the:

- first object
- last object
- and each iteration in between

I need to always update the previous object, and then if the index is the last element, update **just** the last one.

I've been staring at this for a few hours and can't seem to get my head around the complexity of what I've written, there could be a simpler way or I might just be missing one thing.

An example of an array with 3 items looks like:

```js
const example = [
  {
    loaded_at: '2021-07-26 16:31:45',
    duration: 0,
    url: 'https://example.com/1'
  },
  {
    loaded_at: '2021-07-26 16:31:49',
    duration: 0,
    url: 'https://example.com/2'
  },
  {
    loaded_at: '2021-07-26 16:32:27',
    duration: 0,
    url: 'https://example.com/3'
  }
]
```

And my function which right now has a rather confusing set of `if/else` statements to essentially check what position of the iteration of the loop is based on the final array length and update my `previous` and `current` accordingly:

```js
// dedupe functioon
function durationFromData (data) {
  for (const [index, redirect] of data.entries()) {

    let pos = index - 1
    if (data.length == 2) {
      if (index == 0) pos = index - 1
      if (index == 1) pos = index
    } else if (data.length > 2) {
      pos = index - 1
      if (index + 1 == data.length) pos = data.length - 1
    }

    // calculate the difference
    const previous = dayjs(data[pos].loaded_at)
    const current = dayjs(redirect.loaded_at)

    // on page for
    const pageDuration = current.diff(previous, 'second')

    // update durations
    data[pos].duration = pageDuration
  }

  return data
}

console.log(durationFromData(example))
```

Comment: Is the current duration the difference between the current index "loaded_at" and the previous?

Comment: Exactly that yes! Except, the last object never gets populated with a value, and equally similar with the first object if there's only one, thus the shuffling of indexes to try to put them into the ones they need to go in

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to check if the **current index** (`index`) is equal to 0. If true, since we are in the first element you cannot do anything, index -1 doesn´t exist. And call `continue`. it would skip the following loop code and go to the next iteration.

```
function durationFromData (data) {
  for (const [index, redirect] of data.entries()) {

    if (index === 0)
       continue;

    let pos = index - 1
       
    // calculate the difference
    const previous = dayjs(data[pos].loaded_at)
    const current = dayjs(redirect.loaded_at)

    // on page for
    const pageDuration = current.diff(previous, 'second')

    // update durations
    data[pos].duration = pageDuration
  }

  return data
}

console.log(durationFromData(example))
```

Comment: Okay, so I tried that, and the duration for the first obj is 3s which is correct, but the 2nd is 0 and 3rd is 0 when the `loaded_at` times are as follows in order: `2021-07-26 17:13:28`, `2021-07-26 17:13:31`, `2021-07-26 17:14:10`

Comment: Ahh yes, my fault. You just need to skip when index is equal to 0, but not the last index. Try now! The 3rd value should mantain to zero.

Comment: Sweet, I'll have to give this a go tomorrow!

Comment: With the above, do I still need `if (data.length - 1 === index || index === 0) continue` and then add `if (index === 0) continue` beneath it? Still not getting any values for the third object in the list

Comment: No, you just need the `if (index === 0)`. The last element (in this case 3rd) would always be 0 because the code only update the *previous* element with the difference. What value do you expect in the 3rd? I thought it needs to be 0